# Why would you ever call accept() with addr and addrlen set to 0?

Tags: linux, sockets, 64-bit, system-calls

While looking at the syscalls made by a linux executable, I saw this one that struck me as odd:

`accept(fd, 0, 0);`

Why would addr and addrlen be set to 0?

I was also unable to connect to the port that the executable was listening on, but I don't think this accept() call has anything to do with that. Please correct me if I am wrong about this.

Comment: When you don't want the address data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second and third parameters are the protocol address and its length.  If they are not NULL `accept` will fill them in with the info of the client that connected.  If you don't care or don't have a need to know who the client is you can pass those values in as NULL to `accept` and they won't be returned.

It would probably look more normal as

```
accept(fd, NULL, NULL);
```

In terms of usage its probably a little odd that we don't see this form more regularly.  A lot of people go through the trouble of passing the `sockaddr` struct and never use the returned information anyway. And if you do need the info down the line you can always call `getpeername` on the connected socket.

Comment: Thanks. After looking into it, it seems what I see lines up with what you said.